# How do I check if a user has like a property

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I'm making a property advertisement website. In the app users can like or 'star' a property. This created a record in the starred table with the property_id, and the user_id.

I want to check if the user has like the current property so they can't like it again.

This is all on the API end at the moment.

Here is my controller

This creates the liked/starred record.

```
public function store(Property $property, User $user, Request $request)
    {     
        $starred = StarredProperty::create(['property_id' => $property->id, 'user_id' => $user->id]);

        return $starred;
    }
```

This is the starred property model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;


class StarredProperty extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = ['property_id', 'user_id'];
}
```

This is the user model with a relationship for all starred properties.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Property;
use App\StarredProperty;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;


class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'phone_number', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function properties()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Property::class);
    }

    public function starredProperties()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(StarredProperty::class);
    }


    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }


    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply add a check in the controller for this. You could alter your code to something like this:

```php
public function store(Property $property, User $user, Request $request)
{
    if (! $user->starredProperties()->where('property_id', $property->id)->exists()) {
        $starred = StarredProperty::create(['property_id' => $property->id, 'user_id' => $user->id]);

        return $starred;
   }

   // Return whatever else you want here if they have already starred the property
}
```

Comment: The query is fine. I'd place the code for the check in a model method though, as you will need to check the same thing both in the frontend (to change the icon of the like button) as well as in the controller (like shown in the answer).

Comment: Thanks. I extracted the query to the StarredProperty property model which I access via a use relationship.